# How to extract content between two custom strings in Word and paste in end

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to extract contents (Everything including formatting, images, tables etc) between two strings in Word using VBA.

I am able to extract Text only.

Kindly guide me, How can I extract everything between two strings ?

Below is my code

```
Sub ExtractContent()

    Dim startTerm As String
    Dim stopTerm As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim MyArray() As Variant


    Dim startPosition As Long 'Stores the starting position of startTerm
    Dim stopPosition As Long 'Stores the starting position of stopTerm based on first term's location
    Dim nextPosition As Long 'The next position to search for the startTerm

    nextPosition = 1
    counter = 0

    startTerm = "<Question Start>"
    stopTerm = "<Question End>"

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range


    I = 1
    Do Until nextPosition = 0
        startPosition = InStr(nextPosition, myRange, startTerm, vbTextCompare)
        stopPosition = InStr(startPosition, myRange, stopTerm, vbTextCompare)
        myString = Mid$(myRange, startPosition + Len(startTerm), stopPosition - startPosition - Len(startTerm))

        ReDim Preserve MyArray(I)
        MyArray(I) = myString
        MsgBox MyArray(I)
        counter = counter + 1
        I = I + 1
        nextPosition = InStr(stopPosition, myRange, startTerm, vbTextCompare)
    Loop


    'MsgBox counter

     Dim insertPosition As Range
        Set insertPosition = ActiveDocument.Range

        Dim inputWord As Variant
        For Each inputWord In MyArray
            insertPosition.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'Value 0, Can ignore writing it as well
            insertPosition = inputWord & vbCrLf
        Next

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through strings, define a range between two string using Find method.Copy that range to end of Documents (If I understood correctly from your code). It will copy every thing in that range including tables, shapes etc
May try modified tested code:

```
Sub ExtractContent()
    Dim startTerm As String
    Dim stopTerm As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim startPosition As Long 'Stores the starting position of startTerm
    Dim stopPosition As Long 'Stores the starting position of stopTerm based on first term's location


    startTerm = "<Question Start>"
    stopTerm = "<Question End>"

    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    With myRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = startTerm
    .Forward = True
    .Execute

        If .Found Then
        startPosition = myRange.End
        End If
    End With

    If startPosition = 0 Then
    MsgBox startTerm & "Not  Found "
    Exit Sub
    End If


    Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
    With myRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Text = stopTerm
    .Execute
        If .Found Then
        stopPosition = myRange.Start
        End If
    End With

    If stopPosition < startPosition Then
    MsgBox stopTerm & "Not  Found "
    Exit Sub
    End If

     Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(startPosition , stopPosition )
     myRange.Copy
     Dim insertPosition As Range
     Set insertPosition = ActiveDocument.Range
     insertPosition.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     insertPosition.Paste

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @ahmed-au for guiding me. It is working. But copying only first selection. I put last few lines in a loop and then it worked for all selection ranges.  

How can I store all these selected range values in an array. I want to shuffle all elements of array and retrieve them in new word file. Kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: @Dhruva Please take the time to read in the site's [help] about how to ask questions and use Stack Overflow's Q&A format. This is not a typical "forum". If you have a new issue, you need to ask a new question, not try to follow-up in comments.